# Facebook warning for app: asks for read and write permissions at the same time

Tags: facebook

Hello I received this warning from facebook developer:

Your app asks for read and write permissions at the same time. You should only ask for write permissions when a user tries to share something to Facebook.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include [Extended Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) to be able to use "publish_actions".

[This guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/) explains how to set permissions and publish a post to a wall. Esentially, the required permission as stated earlier is included like so:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
```

To publish a story, they have even provided the necessary code for you which also utilises the "publish_actions" permissions:

```
private void publishStory() {
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

if (session != null){

    // Check for publish permissions    
    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        return;
    } ... }
```

And they furthermore check for the permissions by using this code:

```
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
for (String string : subset) {
    if (!superset.contains(string)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

}

This means, that you will only need to utilise write permissions, rather than read permissions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you David. It seems that my app is doing correctly. Grabbing user information is >> Reading...
Sharing on user's wall >> Writing.
 The facebook warning was an "attention" and not a "fix now", so I suppose it was only a suggestion. Or do you think is more important? Thanks again.

Comment: No, if you are simply using the Extended Permissions and "publish_actions" hereof, I would ignore the warning as you would by then seem to use the permissions correctly. Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
In the rare case your app requires publishing permissions up front (for example, an app that does nothing but publish a user's mood to Facebook).
(1)first request the bare minimum read permissions at initial login. After the user logs in with Facebook, 
(2)show the user a screen explaining why your app needs publishing permissions and let the user opt-in to the publishing permission request by clicking a button. 
 This will provide the user more context and improve your conversion.

Another legitimate case for requesting read and publish permissions back-to-back is for users that log in to your app with email or a non-Facebook login option. 
When these users want to publish to Facebook, your app will need to request read permissions to connect their account followed by publishing permissions back-to-back. 
In this case, make sure that the only read permissions you request are public profile and friend list. 
This provides the best user experience because the user wants to simply publish from your app and is not interested in providing additional read permissions. 
It will also improve your conversion.
```